# What is the efficiency of this algorithm which decides the answer to the Boolean satisfiability problem?

Tags: computability-theory, np

I have just written a short javascript program which, given any boolean expression with $N$ variables, completes in N "ticks" of the clock and which makes the decision.  I will explain this algorithm, make some remarks, and post the code so that its clear exactly what I am doing.

- make 2 objects that holds an array, initialize one to [true], the other to [false]
- each timestep, self-replicate the most recently made objects twice each, and append true, false to the array
- after N timesteps, every possible set of values for the boolean variables will be in memory
- if the object detects it has the correct length to do the check, then check it and update a global variable
- after you check every case *in a single timestep (click of the js engine) because I used self-replicating objects*, terminate the program

I have been working very hard on some really exciting new programming approaches using "computer virus techniques" to write normal non-malicious programs.  From a practical point of view, this algorithm takes N clicks, which means it takes N steps to check all $2^N$ cases, where each step is what I call a "click" of the javascript engine.  It's like a timestep in the theory of Turing Machines.

For my practical concerns, I can now check in n-clicks of the js engine the answer to any decision problem of this type.

1. What is the efficiency of this algorithm if not equal to the number of ticks of the javascript engine?  I claim the efficiency of $O(N)$, is this wrong?

To run the code you can copy/paste it into a text file and save it with a .html extension and open that file in your browser.  Just type any javascript boolean expression with an arbitrary number of variables. For example you can type `b1 && b2 || b3` into the input field and click evaluate and check the console log, name all your variables b + number.

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Boolean satisfiability problem</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        input { width: 100%; padding: 4px; font-size: 16px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Type a Boolean expression in javascript using variables b1, b2, b3, ... </p>
    <input id="expression" type="text" name="expression" />
    <button id="evaluate">Evaluate</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('evaluate').onclick = function() {
            var isSatisfiable = false,
                numChecked = 0,
                val = document.getElementById('expression').value,
                match = val.match(/b[0-9]*/g);

            if ( !match.length ) {
                console.log('no match!');
                return;
            }

            var totalCases = Math.pow(2, match.length);

            function BioObject(value) {
                if ( value.length === match.length ) {
                    var params = {};
                    match.forEach(function(item, idx) {
                        params[item] = value[idx];
                    });

                    with (params) {
                        if ( eval(val) ) {
                            isSatisfiable = true
                        }

                        if ( ++numChecked >= totalCases ) {
                            if ( isSatisfiable ) {
                                console.log('is satisfiabile');
                            } else {
                                console.log('cannot be satisfied');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                            var t = value.slice(),
                                f = value.slice();

                            t.push(true)
                            f.push(false)

                            new BioObject(t)
                            new BioObject(f)
                    }, 1)
                }
            }

            new BioObject([true]);
            new BioObject([false]);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```
````

Comment: if this question is not appropriate pls let me know and i will delete and post on another site and apologize in that case

Answer (score 4):

> What is the efficiency of this algorithm if not equal to the number of ticks of the javascript engine? I claim the efficiency of 
>   $O(N)$, is this wrong?

To claim a time efficiency, you (formally) have to specify a computational model. Most people don't because of some vague sense (formalized partially in some things like the Church Turing thesis), all "reasonable" computational models are equivalent (up to polynomial factors) in time complexity.

Your model appears to be inequivalent. The statement:

> each timestep, self-replicate the most recently made objects twice each, and append true, false to the array

Implies that in $N$ time steps you could create $2^N$ objects. This would mean that the space complexity of your algorithm is *not* upper bounded by the time complexity, which is generally the case (for example, in the RAM or Turing Machine model).
It seems like the quantity $O(N)$ in your model would be a better match for the depth of some circuit, but I'm unaware if even this perspective is interesting.

I suspect simulating your computational model with a Turing machine would require $\Omega(2^N)$ time. If you could show this isn't the case it would be interesting, but otherwise you've found a way to rewrite the brute force solution to SAT in a computational model which violates the Church Turing thesis. This can be fine in certain cases (quantum computation is thought to violate the Church turing thesis), but that's because we think that (single) other case could potentially be executed in "polynomial time" in a real life system. Without a demonstration that you can solve hard instances of SAT quickly (which you should be able to do if you have a linear time algorithm), most would find your algorithm unconvincing.

If you wish to "experimentally test" your algorithm, you could generate hard instances of SAT, and see if it preforms well on them.
It's fairly well known that SAT can be fairly easy "on average" (I believe SAT solvers can do better than $O(1.2^n)$ for fairly natural distributions), but is hard in the worst case, especially on problem instances generated from reducing "hard problems" to SAT.

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/9809117.pdf) discusses generating hard SAT instances via reducing factoring to SAT.
If you implement this (or find a program implementing it), and demonstrate you can factor large numbers efficiently, it would go a LONG ways towards justifying that you have a breakthrough.

Comment: My computational model is I gave Turing Machines a new property where they can self-replicate, I have been trying to ask the question if this is ok or not?  Thanks so much for this helpful answer.  I have been working on the theory of self reproducing machines for 15 years and am trying to find out why I cant add a self-replicating property to generalize the theory of computation.  this is my real question

Comment: After working on the formal theory of these "computer virus type methods" I made the following conjecture:
"The theory of self reproducing Turing machines is a Turing complete theory of computation which contains Turing Machines as a special case.  Self reproducing machines can solve NP problems in P time, but without the self-replicating part this is not possible"

I have been trying to formalize these ideas and felt the MO community would be able to put me on the right track.  Thanks!

Comment: Adding a self-replicating property does not seem to generalize the theory of computation --- your machine does not appear to be able to compute new languages that turing machines can't, the only real difference is how efficiently each model computes functions.

So you *can* generalize things by giving a machine more powers, but you both need to be careful about it (a common generalization is via the notion of an oracle machine, and I don't see how to write your computational model as turing machines + an oracle), but moreover you need to have a reason *why* you do it for other people to care

Comment: Essentially plenty of people can propose plenty of different models, but practitioners won't care unless the new model somehow is insightful (usually, via the new model telling us something new about the old model). Your model in particular seems uninteresting at face value because the "self replicating" property does a non-constant amount of work in each time step ---- in the first time step it does "0 work", in the second it does "2 work", then "4 work", etc etc. This corresponds to a computer whos computational powers increase exponentially over time, which is quite different from ...

Comment: Traditional models of computation (where the idea is to stitch together "weak operations" into solving problems, analogous to how all computer programs get compiled down to some fixed instruction set of (relatively) "simple" operations). Essentially this *could* be formalized, but it's not immediately clear *why* other people would be interested. For some pointers to "faster than turing machine" results that people who care about turing machines still care about, see results on oracle machines (Toda's theorem is probably the best example).

Comment: thank you!  This is so helpful.  I am trying really hard to phrase my question properly for a MO audience.  I have discovered a deep insight into how the cell-replication in the human nervous system has a massive computational power.  How can we mathematically capture the computational power of the human nervous system based on cell self-repliaction?  For me, giving a self-replication property to a Turing Machine is a natural generalization because its just a Turing Machine that can "3d print" itself in an abstract world of ideas

Comment: at this time, my question is: what information might I be missing in order to appropriately pose a question to the MO community about the computational complexity of the human nervous system cell self-replication process?  I very much want to make a positive contribution to this community with on-topic questions and am willing to work very hard to provide any required work/demonstrations on my part.  I am struggling to give meaningful definitions to some of my ideas, and have a background on comp-sci.  Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106048/discussion-between-mark-and-matt-calhoun).